# php mail with socket

Tags: php, sockets, email, smtp

I'm trying to sent mail with php via socket. I'm write the follwoing code:

```
 $data="EHLO myName\r\n"."auth login\r\n"."mybase64login\r\n"."mybase64pass=\r\n"."mail from: mymail@gmyhost.com\r\n"."rcpt to: mymail@myhost.com\r\n"."data\r\n"."Sender:".$_GET['name']."\r\n"."Phone:".$_GET['phone']."\r\n"."Email:".$_GET['email']."\r\n"."Msg:".$_GET['msg']."\r\n".".\r\n";
      $fp=  fsockopen("smtp.myhost.com", 25);
      fputs($fp, $data);
      echo fgets($fp);
```

But I recieve only connection established message from the server. I don't recieve greeting message, auth message, etc. Why it's occuring?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
fputs($fp, "EHLO your.domain\r\n");
fputs($fp, "AUTH LOGIN\r\n");
fputs($fp, "MAIL FROM:" . $from_mail . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, base64_encode($login) . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, base64_encode($password) . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, "RCPT TO:" . $mail_to . "\r\n");
fputs($fp, "DATA\r\n");
fputs($fp, $header . "\r\n" . $text . "\r\n.\r\n");
fputs($fp, "QUIT\r\n");
```

Comment: It doesn't work to. Even when I'm trying to sent only greeting command I've no greeting response from server. But I can send message via telnet.

Comment: As it is my working code I humbly suppose the problem might be in your credentials or network settings.